# Regex-function adds second occurance of pattern to first one

Tags: php, regex, markdown

The `preg_match_all()`-function should find all occurances of this `/\]\(.*.md\)/`-Expression, it does, but somehow it detects multiple matches just as one.
My input looks like this:

```
[example](foo/random/link.md) | [example2](other/some.md)
Lorem ipsum.....
[example3](foo/Readme.md)
```

It should match the three `examples`-links. But it returns:

```
Array[0] -> ](foo/random/link.md) | [example2](other/some.md)
Array[1] -> ](../Readme.md)
```

Although `example2` should also be found. I am quite confident it is a problem with the use of `.*`, but I was not able to come up with something better.

P.S.: For better understanding. I am writing a php-script that translates links from markdown docs to links that are relative to the php-scripts position in the filesystem.

Comment: try changing it to `.*?`

Comment: Also, there should be `\ ` before `.md`. the modified regex should be `/\]\(.*?\.md\)/`

Comment: @Matt.G Thanks! It worked. From now on more regex-reading for me

Comment: As matt probably *should* have explained, the `?` makes the `*` matching "un-greedy" so that it stops sooner [at the first `)`] rather than later. [at the last `)`]